# Magento - adding custom attribute to Customer model

Tags: magento

i'm trying to add an attribute to customer model. it a select list which allow customer to select, during registration, the job's category:

```
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'customer_sector', array(
     'label' => 'Settore',
     'type' => 'int',
     'input' => 'select',
     'default' => '0',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'default_value' => '',
    'visible' => 1,
     'user_defined' => 1,
    'searchable' => 1,
    'filterable' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
    'visible' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'required' => false,
    // what i have to add on 'global'?
    //'global'  => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'option'  => array ('value' => array(1 => array('opzione 1'),2 => array('opzione     2'), 3 => array('opzione 3')))
));
```

is my code correct? i've found a guide on magentocommerce.com (and also many similar question here) but it explain how to add custom attributes on products, so i prefer to ask here.

thx

LuKe

Comment: @AntonS: Magento 1.4.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these links:

- [Adding customer attributes and displaying them in the Magento admin](http://web.archive.org/web/20131125225742/http://www.echotrue.com/articles/adding-customer-attributes-and-displaying-them-in-the-magento-admin)
- [Adding Custom Signup Attributes](https://web.archive.org/web/20120726000003/http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/custom-customer-signup-attributes)

Comment: Always add the relevant infos from the linked article to your post, because links can die! Your second link is dead.

Comment: @Black you are right, I have fixed by webarchive, check it again.

Comment: You have to include all relevant infos in the post, the links can die again.